# updating a session id in a MySQL db - PHP

Tags: php

The following function is supposed to take in a `PHP` `session_id` and update it, otherwise the user will be logged out in 5 min:

```
function update_session_id( $session_id = "" )
{
    $stmt = "UPDATE session SET start=NOW() WHERE id='$session_id';";
    $query = mysql_query( $stmt )
        or die( mysql_error() );

    if( $query )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For some reason, `PHP` is returning me `"\"p9bb7t9gmchtvr6scr8hseufm6\""` even though I'm using `stripslashes()`, which does not seems to remove those slashes at all. That's why my query is not working ... 
The code where that function is called it's pretty simple:

```
else if( strcmp( $action, "query" ) == 0 )
    {
        $session_id = stripslashes( $_POST['session_id'] );
        $data = getCustomer();
        update_session_id( $session_id );
        echo json_encode( $session_id );
    }
```

but I don't know why I'm getting those extra slashes on my string. Any thoughts?
**Update** A query example:

```
"UPDATE session SET start=NOW() WHERE id='\"p9bb7t9gmchtvr6scr8hseufm6\"';"
```

Comment: Why would there be double quotes in your session id to begin with? What do you mean by PHP is returning that value to you? Why are you posting session id's rather than using normal session functionality?

Comment: Escape parameters in your MySQL queries! (Seriously... how many times am I going to have to say this...)

Comment: Also, have you thought of simply using a cookie for the session id, rather than posting it? That's the (much) more standard approach.

Comment: @Endophage I tried using `mysql_real_escape_string` but I get: `UPDATE session SET start=NOW() WHERE id=\'\"p9bb7t9gmchtvr6scr8hseufm6\"\';INSER
T INTO session( id, start ) VALUES ( '6prdfd4t2ejoqc26790it9ofc0', '2012-12-13 02:47:59' )`

Comment: That value is $ _POST ['session_id']?

Comment: @alditis yes that's the value of `$ _POST ['session_id']?`

Answer (score 1):

The correct code to generate the statement is:

```
$stmt = sprintf("UPDATE session SET start=NOW() WHERE id='%s'", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($session_id)
);
```

If you see double quotes in the resulting query, that means the double quotes were **already there**.

See also: [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/pdo)